# Giving email account a name when sending emails with Django through Google Apps

Tags: django, email, smtp

I am sending emails to users using Django through Google Apps.

When the user receives emails sent from the Django app, they are from:
`do_not_reply@domain.example`

when looking at all emails in the inbox, people see the email's sender as:
`do_not_reply` or `do_not_reply@domain.example` depending on the email client used

If I log into that "do_not_reply" account using the browser and Google Apps itself and then send an email to myself, the emails are from:
`Don't Reply <do_not_reply@domain.example>`

As a result, the name displayed for the email's sender in the inbox is:
`Don't Reply`

In Django, is there a way to attach a "name" to the email account being used to send emails?

I have reviewed Django's `mail.py`, but had no luck finding a solution
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/mail.py?rev=5548

Using:

- Django 1.1
- Python 2.6
- Ubuntu 9.1
- `settings.EMAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com`

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can actually use `"Don't Reply <do_not_reply@domain.example>"` as the email address you send from.

Try this in the shell of your Django project to test if it also works with gapps:

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('subject', 'message', "Don't Reply <do_not_reply@domain.example>", ['youremail@example.com'])
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! Wish I had seen this yesterday b/c it would have saved me some time. I was just reading the documentation over at <http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects> and finally read the "from_email" more closely and found the same answer as you. Was just coming here to post an answer when I saw yours. Anyway, thanks again! Glad to finally have this working

Comment: You can also set DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL on settings.py like this:

`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Dont Reply <do_not_reply@domain.com>'`

Comment: Just make sure, you dont set the same email with name as auth_user , because it will fail while authentication

Comment: @iamkhush - What do you mean by `setting the same email with name as aut_user`. I'm getting an authentication error. I couldn't understand why?

Comment: If you want to have do_not_reply@domain.com as the display name, use `'"do_not_reply@domain.com" <do_not_reply@domain.com>'` (note the `"`'s around the display name. Otherwise django will complain

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the send_mail method to send email, EmailMultiAlternatives can also be used to send email with HTML content with text content as an alternative.

try this in your project

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
text_content = "Hello World"
# set html_content
email = EmailMultiAlternatives('subject', text_content, 'Dont Reply <do_not_reply@domain.example>', ['youremail@example.com'])

email.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
email.send()
```

This will send mail to `youremail@example.com` with Don't Reply wil be displayed as name instead of email `do_not_reply@domain.example`.

Answer (score -6):

I use this code to send through gmail smtp (using google apps). and sender names are OK

```
def send_mail_gapps(message, user, pwd, to):
    import smtplib
    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(user, pwd)
    mailServer.sendmail(user, to, message.as_string())
    mailServer.close()
```

Comment: This is actually the same code that Django's EmailMessage classes uses in the background. Regardless, I tried your method and the email still has `do_not_reply` as the sender's name. Thanks for trying though

Comment: and what about settings.DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM ?