# How to specify name in Django mail?

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django's core.mail package in conjunction with django-registration for a new user sign up workflow.  I have an email account, "no-reply@(mycompany).com" through my company's google mail service, that i want to use to send these emails.  In the google mail account settings i set the name for the email account as "(MyCompany) Support" so that if I mail directly from google mail, the emails come in  from the account as being from "(MyCompany) Support ".  However, when i use django's email settings to send mail, the emails show up in a client's email box as being from "no-reply" which is ugly and may be a bit off-putting to a new client.  Is there a way to specify a "Name" for an email address when sending using django's built-in mailer so that the see the "Name" displayed when they get the email?

Here are my current settings in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='no-reply@mycompany.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='**********'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111452/giving-email-account-a-name-when-sending-emails-with-django-through-google-apps

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use

```
"(MyCompany) Support <no-reply@mycompany.com>"
```

as the from address in the call to send_mail.

Answer (score 17):

Those solutions are useful if you're using django's email package directly.  However, i didn't want to look for a hook to override the way that django-registration uses send_mail so I found the following setting when going through the django files, which lets you set a default from email.

```
 DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='(My Company) Support <no-reply@mycompany.com>'
```

and it worked!

Figured someone else may find it useful, although i'm not so pretentious as to mark my own answer as correct.

Comment: Looks like you can put the same value in for `SERVER_EMAIL` as well!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ADMINS` and `MANAGERS` tuples in `setting.py`. E.g.:

```
ADMINS = (('Your Name', 'email@company.com),)
```

And then:

```
django.core.email.mail_managers('subject', 'body')
```

Answer (score 2):

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='(My Company) Support '

Helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another explicit way is to use the [`Address`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.headerregistry.html#email.headerregistry.Address)

read my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72685358/15993687)

```
from email.headerregistry import Address

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = Address(display_name="Company Name", addr_spec="info@domain.com")
```